# How do I apply a lifecycle rule to an EXISTING s3 bucket in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

New to Terraform. Trying to apply a lifecycle rule to an existing s3 bucket declared as a datasource, but I guess I can't do that with a datasource - throws an error. Here's the gist of what I'm *trying* to achieve:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "test-bucket" {
  bucket = "bucket_name"
  lifecycle_rule {
    id = "Expiration Rule"
    enabled = true
    prefix = "reports/"
    expiration {
      days = 30
    }
  }
}
```

...and if this were a resource, not a datasource, then it would work. How can I apply a lifecycle rule to an s3 bucket declared as a data source? Google Fu has yielded little in the way of results. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to import your bucket to terraform state instead of using it as `data`.

For that try to put this on your terraform code:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test-bucket" {
  bucket = "bucket_name"
  lifecycle_rule {
    id = "Expiration Rule"
    enabled = true
    prefix = "reports/"
    expiration {
      days = 30
    }
  }
}
```

And then run on the terminal:

`terraform import aws_s3_bucket.test-bucket bucket_name`

This will import the bucket to your state and now you can make the changes or add new things to your bucket using terraform.

Last step just run `terraform apply` and the lifecycle rule will be added.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Nice ! No problem!